# Server to server postbacks

Tags: asp.net, architecture, postback

This is more to do with architecture, but anyway, I will ask the question.

I have a scenario, where I have some servers running on the internal network. Is it possible to post from a server on internal network, to an external server and then the external server doing a server to server postback on to the original server?

```
                     Server to server postback
Internal Server -------------------------------
      |                                        |
      |                                        |
      |         Post to external server        |
   Web Page  ---------------------------- External Server
      |
      |
   Customer
```

Comment: Perhaps have a look at WCF. Make a request from the internal server and get a response from the external server. +1 on the diagram.

Comment: In principle you can always have servers talking to each other. How you do it for your application is dependent on a whole load of detail you haven't posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible but you may have to make adjustments to your firewall to allow traffic into your internal network. From an http request point of view it's not a problem, but your infrastructure must allow it (permissions)

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, to do this you must make the internal server "external", at least to the other external server.  The external server will have to open a network connection to the internal one.  This will have a couple of problems,

1. the internal server doesn't have a public IP address,
2. the firewall will prevent the connection
3. your IT folks will be cranky with you for exposing an external server to the outside world.

You have a couple of options:

1. open a port on the firewall to the internal server
2. put the internal server in the DMZ
3. setup a relay in the DMZ that can connect to both the internal and be visible to the outside world.  Sometimes companies have things like this already set up.  See if they have something like an F5 Big-IP load balancer/router already in place.

Comment: I will need to talk to the network guys to get this done. Not sure how happy will they be.